# Getting questions with multiple tags

Tags: support, questions

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/gwt,google-app-engine returns nothing, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt+google-app-engine does have plenty of entries. And http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/tagged/gwt+google-app-engine has no contents.

Comment: should be noted that 'questions/tagged' has been removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/?tagged=gwt+google-app-engine